# Copying contents of current directory to a subdirectory

Tags: linux, console, terminal

How can I use the Linux terminal to copy everything in current directory to a subdirectory?

Comment: Do you mean copy or move?

Answer (score 13):

If you want to copy the contents of the folder recursively (will throw 1 error, alternatives below):

```
cp -r * sub/
```

A little more hacky, but works on non-empty subdirectories:

```
TARGETDIR='targetdir here';cp -r `find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name "$TARGETDIR"` "$TARGETDIR"
```

Another oneliner:

```
TARGETDIR='targetdir here';for file in *;do test "$file" != "$TARGETDIR" && cp "$file" "$TARGETDIR/";done
```

Or recursive:

```
TARGETDIR='z';for file in *;do test "$file" != "$TARGETDIR" && cp -r "$file" "$TARGETDIR/";done
```

Comment: this does not work in case sub/ is not empty -> sub will copied into sub again, unless that is what @Oguz wanted.

Comment: Ok I'm finally satisfied with the `find` code :D

Comment: Your second command fails for filenames that include spaces. Use `xargs` or `-exec`. No need for `grep` - use `! -name "$TARGETDIR"` or similar. You have unmatched quotes around `$file`. I don't think a recursive `cp` will work the way you intend in any but your first command.

Comment: Wohaa, missed a quote in the last codes. Good comment Dennis, I never thought of using -name in this case :)

Answer (score 5):

Supposing `target` is the name of the target subdirectory, if your shell is bash:

```
shopt -s extglob
cp -r !(target) target/
```

In ksh, you can directly do `cp -r !(target) target/`.

In zsh, you can do `setopt ksh_glob` then `cp -r !(target) target/`. Another possibility is `setopt extended_glob` then `cp -r ^target target/`.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest moving the target directory outside the source directory and then put it back again; mv is free (if you are careful not to move to a different filesystem), unless you are expecting other processes to interfere/be interfered.

Most solutions posted above won't work if there are spaces in filenames. I would suggest using variants of find -print0 | xargs -0, or find -exec, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

```
cp -r * subdir/
```

If you meant to move instead of copying everything in the current dir to a subdirectory, you could do:

```
mv * subdir/
```

Comment: this does not take care of non-empty directories

Comment: I just tested, and it worked.

Comment: you need to copy the non-empty directories recursively like @Lekensteyn suggested.

Comment: will throw error `cp: cannot copy a directory, 'a', into itself, 'a/a'`

Answer (score -1):

This goes in say file dirCopy.sh

```
for i in `ls`
do
        if [ $i != "subDir" ]
        then
                `cp -r $i subDir`
        fi
done
```

run it as " sh dirCopy.sh " in your console

Comment: No need for `ls`: `for file in *`. No need for backticks - use `$()`. No need for backticks (or `$()`) around the `cp` command (that will produce an error message).

Answer (score -1):

This will copy everything, including dot files, and not including the target directory itself, to the target directory `SUBDIR`:

```
for i in `ls -a | grep -Ev '^(SUBDIR|\.\.?)$'`; do cp $i SUBDIR; done
```

Comment: Fails for filenames that include spaces.